# MongoDb Pipeline Aggregation to get sub sub documents returns same number

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pipeline, mongoose-schema

I have School, Class and Student models and schema

```
 School(_id,
       stx:{type:string,required:false},
       category: {type:string,required: false}
       location:{type:string,required:false},
       classes?:[Class])
```

and

```
Class(_id,
   level:{type:number,required:false},
   classesCount:{type:number,required:false},
   students?:[Student])`
```

and

```
Student(_id,
  age:{type:number,required:false},
  boyz:{type:number,required:false},
  girls:{type:number,required:false})
```

And here's my pipeline to group by stx, location and level.

```
const pipeline = SchoolModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {year: '2021-2022'}
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$classes"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$classes.students"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        stx: "$stx",
        location: "$location",
        level: "$classes.level"
      },
      boyz: {
        $sum: "$classes.students.boyz"
      },
      girls: {
        $sum: "$classes.students.girls"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      stx: "$_id.stx",
      location: "$_id.location",
      level: "$_id.classes.level",
      boyz: 1,
      girls: 1,
    }
  }
]);

const results = await pipeline.exec();

res.status(200).json(results);
```

Why does this pipeline wrongly return same girls and boyz count in the result per each same level? How better unwind and/group sub sub documents?

PS: This occurs only if I group by a Class property. When I group by school category it returns correct values.

Comment: can u give some sample data. or create a mongoplayground and share

Comment: What does it return? What should it return?  What do the schemas look like?

Comment: I edited the question with details